# How can I configure SASS to compile specific stylesheets into a separate desktop and mobile version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

I'm running Rails 3.1 along with Sass. I now need to segment my stylesheets into a mobile version as well as a desktop version. By default sass-rails is compressing every .scss file in my assets/stylesheets/ path into one application.css file.

I would like, instead, to explicitly tell Sass to compiled scss file X into mobile.css and files Y & Z into desktop.css

Is this accomplished via a config.sass value? I really appreciate the help on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application %>

And application.scss looks like:

```
*= require_self
*= require_tree
```

Instead of sprocket's manifest for require files, use sass's includes. To still use application.scss, remove the line `*= require_tree`

So <%= stylesheet_link_tag :mobile %>

/app/assets/stylesheets/mobile.scss

```
@import "bootstrap/bootstrap.scss";
@import "typography.scss";
body {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
```

And you'd do the same for desktop.scss. Note: you'll have to manually add each file you want to import.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the answer. Yes, I had forgotten about the manifest area at the top of application.scss

Answer (score 0):

Use response design instead of server side checks! More progressive/better approach. Plus, your http requests will thank you!

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Or write a method that checks user agent (which I assume you already did) and conditionalize'  the loading of your style